# Android AudioTrack clicks at start and end of sound

Tags: android, audio, wav

I get clicks at the start and end of playing a sound (a wav from the sdcard). It must be something to do with the track buffering but I dont know the solution. Also, I create a new one of these every time the sound plays, is this ok or is there a better way? There are many sounds playing over and over. Here is the code:

```
public void PlayAudioTrack(final String filePath, final Float f) throws IOException
    {

    new Thread(new Runnable() { public void run() { 
            //play sound here
        int minSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize( 44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT );        
           AudioTrack track = new AudioTrack( AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 44100, 
             AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, 
             minSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

        track.setPlaybackRate((int) (44100*f));

    if (filePath==null)
    return;

    int count = 512 * 1024; 
    //Read the file..
    byte[] byteData = null;
    File file = null;
    file = new File(filePath);

    byteData = new byte[(int)count];
    FileInputStream in = null;
    try {
    in = new FileInputStream( file );

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

    int bytesread = 0, ret = 0;
    int size = (int) file.length();

    while (bytesread < size) { 
    try {
        ret = in.read( byteData,0, count);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    track.play(); 
    if (ret != -1) { 
    // Write the byte array to the track 
    track.write(byteData,0, ret); bytesread += ret; 
    } 
    else break; } 

    try {
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } track.stop(); track.release(); 
    }

        }).start();
        }
```

Many thanks for any help

Comment: My  audio experience is not on Android, but it seems odd that you are calling track.play() before writing any bytes to it.  Shouldn't you write the bytes first?

Comment: no, you need to open up the audiotrack with play() then write to it because its mode_streaming. i think its maybe not reading the wav header right or something.

Comment: wtf do you think you are doing ChrisWue? editing random posts to get badges is not really helpfull to anyone is it? you could at least try to answer...

Answer (score 4):

Isn't it possible that you play the PCM wave file header too?

Each PCM wave file has a small header at the beginning of the file, if you play that, you play the header bytes which could result in a click at te beginning.

Comment: Indeed these 44 bytes of WAVE-header sounds like a click if played. The solution is to skip 44 bytes when AT starts playing such file.

Answer (score 1):

I have had these same clicks at the beginning of each track using AudioTrack. I solved it by turning track volume off, waiting half a second, and then restoring normal volume. I no longer have any clicks.  Here's the relevant bit of the code.

```
    at.play();
    at.setStereoVolume (0.0f, 0.0f);

    new Thread (new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            try{
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) { ; }
            at.setStereoVolume (1.0f, 1.0f);
        }
    }).start();

    new Thread (new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            int i = 0;
            try{
                buffer = new byte[512];
                while(((i = is.read(buffer)) != -1) && !paused){
                    at.write(buffer, 0, i);
                    position += i;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (!paused){
                parent.trackEnded();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```