# just hearing clicking noise on audiotrack playback

Tags: android, audiorecord, audiotrack

I'm trying to record sound from the mic and then play it back, but all I here is a clicking sound. Both of the AudioTrack and AudioRecord are on the same settings, and initalised correctly. Here is my code:

```
    stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            isRecording = false;
            recordingThread.join();


            player = findAudioTrack();
            player.play();

            for (int i = 0; i < audioQueue.size(); i++) {
                int written = player.write(audioQueue.get(i), 0,
                        audioQueue.get(i).length);
            }

            player.stop();
            player.release();
            player = null;
        }
    });
}

private void startRecording() {

    recorder = findAudioRecord();

    recorder.startRecording();
    isRecording = true;
    recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            addAudioToQueue();
        }
    }, "AudioRecorder Thread");
    recordingThread.start();
}

private void addAudioToQueue() {
    short[] capturedAudio = new short[recordBufferSize/2];
    while (isRecording) {
        int read = recorder.read(capturedAudio, 0, capturedAudio.length);
        audioQueue.add(capturedAudio);
    }
    recorder.stop();
    recorder.release();
    recorder = null;
}
```

}

Does anyone know why this is?

Here is the full source code:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/h38cs9vjkztyyro/AudioTesting.java

Comment: What's the recording of?

Answer (score 1):

It probably has to do with the fact that you are using a `short` array instead of a `byte` array.

> public int [read](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html#read%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) (byte[] audioData, int offsetInBytes, int sizeInBytes)

It's likely that this function is only filling the first `byte` of each `short` so you are left with half of each index being 1 `byte` of audio data, and the other `byte` being junk or zeroes.

Try using a `byte` array instead of `short`.

Comment: unfortunately I still get the clicking noise

Comment: Perhaps it isn't about how you are recording the audio, but in how you are playing it back?

Comment: possibly, I have added the full source code so feel free to see if my errors are there... I am building a bluetooth VOIP and I copied the code I used from there to build this. The bluetooth VOIP actually works (not great quality but you can hear my voice and understand it) so I cant understand why this doesn't work

Comment: It would seem that clicks while using an `AudioTrack` is a known issue. I would try the fix presented here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203671/android-audiotrack-clicks-at-start-and-end-of-sound Although i am tempted to say i has more to do with either your sample rate or your buffer size. Try playing around with this solution and some of your settings to see if you can make the clicks go away.

Comment: one thing I have noticed is that if I extend a syllable and press stop whilst singing that syllable the track will play just that syllable but nothing i have said before it...